# Can we have p2p like downloading of rpm from repository

Tags: centos7, rpm, p2p

Can anyone please tell me whether its possible to have p2p like downloading of rpm from repository

Comment: The issue with p2p downloading is infrastructure: there are no p2p servers offering repository packages. There is no reason (other than lack of interest) why p2p distribution could not be done. In fact, iso images are often distributed using p2p.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for torrents it takes quite some time to start downloading a file (find peers, who has the file). This is inefficient for small files (average rpm has 800kB). Debian done that and it is not a popular form of transport. It is much faster and easier to have sets of mirrors. Using torrents for images is much better and you can download CentOS images using torrents.

Comment: This answer applies even more with "deltarpm" which is now default on pretty much any system I've touched in the past few years.